# CDH5 can not start Flume agent

Tags: twitter, cloudera, flume

I try to start Flume agent on my AWS EC2 machine (RedHat) with CDH5 installed. I use the command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/flume-ng-agent status
```

and I get the response:

```
-bash: /etc/init.d/flume-ng-agent: No such file or directory
```

I have checked CDH5 guide and it says this is the way to start agent ... what do i do wrong?

When I run flume-ng version I get

```
Flume 1.6.0-cdh5.9.0
```

EDIT: when I run command `sudo service flume-ng-agent stop` than it says `Failed to stop flume-ng-agent.service: Unit flume-ng-agent.service not loaded.`

if I run `flume-ng help I get`

```
Usage: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.9.0-1.cdh5.9.0.p0.23/bin/../lib/flume-ng/bin/flume-ng <command> [options]...
```

if I run flume-ng agent I get fatal error...

```
ERROR node.Application: A fatal error occurred while running. Exception follows.
org.apache.commons.cli.MissingOptionException: Missing required option: n
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.checkRequiredOptions(Parser.java:299)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:231)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:85)
        at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main(Application.java:265)
```

EDIT2:

I get following error when I use command:

```
flume-ng agent -c /etc/flume/conf -f /etc/flume/conf/flume.conf -n


ERROR node.Application: A fatal error occurred while running. Exception follows.
org.apache.commons.cli.MissingArgumentException: Missing argument for option: n
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processArgs(Parser.java:343)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.processOption(Parser.java:393)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:199)
        at org.apache.commons.cli.Parser.parse(Parser.java:85)
        at org.apache.flume.node.Application.main(Application.java:265)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the "-n" you have to specify the name of the agent you want to run from your config file.

If you look at https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#a-simple-example , you can see that there is one agent (`a1`) defined in the config file and there is `--name a1` in the command line example.